# backbone js rigth initialization process

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This `javascript` present on all site pages.

```
    var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.js-categories-view'),

    initialize: function () {
...
    }

...
    templates: {
      'category-template': _.template($('#js-category-template').html())
    },


  });
```

And if page haven't element `$('.js-categories-view')`, code like: `new CategoriesView();` it will not be called and initialize not be called too.

But what about templates section?

`_.template($('#js-category-template').html())` always called and I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Because `$('#js-category-template')` doesn't present on page and and I don't want store template html on page where this View not needed?

Comment: Can you include the `new CategoriesView()` line only in pages that need it?

Comment: Yes I can, but is not the problem. This code code called always: `_.template($('#js-category-template').html())` and error is occuring even new CategoriesView() wasn't called on page. It is going because `$('#js-category-template')` isn't presented on page

Comment: Improved readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the needed element present on the current page like this:

```
if( $('.js-categories-view').length ){
    new CategoriesView();
}
```

And if you want to prevent error when calling the `_.template()` function, you also need to move the definition of the `templates` object into the `initialize` method of the view like follows:

```
var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('.js-categories-view'),

  initialize: function () {
    this.templates = {
      'category-template': _.template($('#js-category-template').html())
    };
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Please see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! It's good solution. But eventually I implement this:

```
    $(function () {

      if (!$('.js-categories-view').length) {
        return;
      }

      var CategoriesPageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      ...
```

to not to think about issues like this. But I think thant better solution can be found